# ActiveRecord with find_by_sql: order by a field from a joined table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a model MobileApp and I use `find_by_sql` to do a complex SQL query with several `INNER JOIN`. The SQL query is the following :

```
SELECT DISTINCT mobile_apps.*, satisfaction_scores.id, satisfaction_scores.score FROM mobile_apps
    INNER JOIN bucket_applications ON mobile_apps.id = bucket_applications.mobile_app_id
    INNER JOIN satisfaction_scores ON mobile_apps.id = satisfaction_scores.mobile_app_id
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT * FROM feeds
        WHERE feeds.mobile_app_id = mobile_apps.id
        AND feeds.target_id = 41
        AND feeds.left IS TRUE) ORDER BY satisfaction_scores.score DESC;
```

And I do a `MobileApp.find_by_sql(<the_query>)`.

My problem is that I need to sort my `MobileApp` by score of `SatisfactionScore`. Consequently, I need to add in the `SELECT` the field `score` to have the `ORDER BY` working with score. I think the SQL query is right, but ActiveRecord doesn't like to have in the `SELECT` columns not from table `mobile_apps` and therefore returns wrong ids of `MobileApp`.

```
MobileApp.find_by_sql(<the_query>) =>
[#<MobileApp id: 41>,
 #<MobileApp id: 42>,
 #<MobileApp id: 43>,
 #<MobileApp id: 44>]
```

But

```
MobileApp.ids => [153, 156, 159, 162, 165]
```

Is there a better way to do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By removing the `satisfaction_scores.id` from the `SELECT`, the `MobileApp` ids returned by the `find_by_sql` are correct. Besides the column `satisfaction_scores.id` was not essential for the query.